# Tabular uneven column bars

Tags: tables

Does anyone know why my double line is shorter than the other single lines?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l||c|c|c|c}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\textsf{Column1}}}&\textbf{\textsf{Column2}}&\textbf{\textsf{Column3}}&\textbf{\textsf{Column4}}\\
A & B & C & D\\
E & F & G & H\\
I & J & K & L\\
\end{tabular}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First: don't use vertical rules. But if you really want them, you have to also add it in your `\multicolumn`, like so: `\multicolumn{1}{c||}{\textbf{\textsf{Column1}}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using vertical rules.

But if you must have them: the rules must be added as part of the `\multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l||c|c|c|c}
\multicolumn{1}{c||}{\textbf{\textsf{Column1}}}&\textbf{\textsf{Column2}}&\textbf{\textsf{Column3}}&\textbf{\textsf{Column4}}\\
A & B & C & D\\
E & F & G & H\\
I & J & K & L\\
\end{tabular}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]